# How to store the filesize in db2

Tags: java, db2, sqldatatypes, springsource

I'm using DB2, and from the UI part when I select the any .doc files, the related information has to get stored in the table, like filename,filesize, file extension(doc,docx,ods etc). 
While creating the table I have mentioned the data type of FileSize as double and when the file size is too large, it is storing as **(1.918208E7)** is there any solution to solve this?? In pojo class, I tried giving the filesize as Double as well as float, both stores the filesize as **1.918208E7**. Is there anthing I have to change in the pojo class or while seeting the filesize in bean?? or its with the sql data type? 
The file size i'm storing is in Bytes
Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileSize seems integer to me - so you should use BIGINT data type which represents 64-bit integer (and 64 bits should be enough to store size in bytes of few Internets)

Comment: Thanks.. It worked. I had used datatype DOUBLE instead of BIGINT. Changed it to BIGINT. Thanks again